# Is there a config to disable/remove the "New" button?

Tags: photoeditorsdk

I'd like to disable to the New control at the top right of the React UI. Is there a configuration option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with the config options, I discovered that if you set both the `enableWebcam` and `enableUpload` keys to false, the New button won't be shown.